# how to connect SQL developer to oracle database in M1 mac

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BAsKnfRHwI&t=205s
so i can open sql developer and install docker preview version for M1 mac here is the link where i downloaded
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/
and i tried so many things to connect those two things but i falied for 3 days..
I'm trying to install oracle 11g with docker but i falied with this message
...
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

fd666a46888100294cf6ce4ab73a371b43da75c76f28e223f96efebb6246daf4
...
anyone knows how do i solve this problem??

Comment: This review says something about docker for x86-64 images having a challenge on M1: https://www.toptal.com/apple/apple-m1-processor-compatibility-overview